# Error while connect to SQL Server with jdbc Logstash

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, logstash, hikaricp, java-14

I have SQL Server in my PC that I login with SSMS with server name = `DESKTOP-XXXX\MSSQLSERVER01`  and windows auth.

What I tried to to is put the data from rabbit mq to SQL Server with Logstash. But I got an error while I running Logstash.

I have java 14 version install as required by Logstash .

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2\bin>java -version
java version "14.0.2" 2020-07-14
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 14.0.2+12-46)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0.2+12-46, mixed mode, sharing)
```

my logs-pipeline.conf :

```
input{
    rabbitmq {
        host => "127.0.0.1" 
        subscription_retry_interval_seconds => 90
        queue => "TestQueue"
        threads => 2
        passive => true
        codec => "json"
    }
}
output {
jdbc{
driver_jar_path => "C:\sqljdbc_6.0\enu\jre8\sqljdbc42.jar"
driver_class => "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
connection_string => "jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-XXXXX\MSSQLSERVER01;databaseName=test;integratedSecurity=true"
statement => [ "INSERT into [test].[dbo].[dbo.class] (first_name) VALUES(?)", "@timestamp" ]


}
}
```

The error while I tried to running Logstash

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2\bin>c:\logstash\bin\logstash.bat -f c:\logstash\config\logs-pipeline.conf
Using JAVA_HOME defined java: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2
WARNING, using JAVA_HOME while Logstash distribution comes with a bundled JDK
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option UseConcMarkSweepGC; support was removed in 14.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction; support was removed in 14.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly; support was removed in 14.0
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.jruby.ext.openssl.SecurityHelper (file:/C:/Users/XXXX/AppData/Local/Temp/jruby-14388/jruby9423128189939798823jopenssl.jar) to field java.security.MessageDigest.provider
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.jruby.ext.openssl.SecurityHelper
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Sending Logstash logs to c:/logstash/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2021-02-07T21:33:56,294][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"7.10.2", "jruby.version"=>"jruby 9.2.13.0 (2.5.7) 2020-08-03 9a89c94bcc Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 14.0.2+12-46 on 14.0.2+12-46 +indy +jit [mswin32-x86_64]"}
[2021-02-07T21:33:56,482][WARN ][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
[2021-02-07T21:33:57,839][INFO ][org.reflections.Reflections] Reflections took 26 ms to scan 1 urls, producing 23 keys and 47 values
[2021-02-07T21:33:58,186][INFO ][logstash.outputs.jdbc    ][main] JDBC - Starting up
[2021-02-07T21:33:58,259][INFO ][com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource][main] HikariPool-1 - Starting...
[2021-02-07T21:34:09,819][ERROR][com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool][main] HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection to the host DESKTOP-XXXX, named instance mssqlserver01 failed. Error: "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out". Verify the server and instance names and check that no firewall is blocking UDP traffic to port 1434.  For SQL Server 2005 or later, verify that the SQL Server Browser Service is running on the host.
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:191) ~[sqljdbc42.jar:?]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.getInstancePort(SQLServerConnection.java:5247) ~[sqljdbc42.jar:?]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.primaryPermissionCheck(SQLServerConnection.java:1871) ~[sqljdbc42.jar:?]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1608) ~[sqljdbc42.jar:?]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1459) ~[sqljdbc42.jar:?]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:773) ~[sqljdbc42.jar:?]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1168) ~[sqljdbc42.jar:?]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:117) ~[HikariCP-2.7.2.jar:?]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:375) ~[HikariCP-2.7.2.jar:?]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:204) ~[HikariCP-2.7.2.jar:?]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:445) [HikariCP-2.7.2.jar:?]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:516) [HikariCP-2.7.2.jar:?]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:116) [HikariCP-2.7.2.jar:?]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:97) [HikariCP-2.7.2.jar:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[?:?]
        at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirectWithExceptionHandling(JavaMethod.java:426) [jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirect(JavaMethod.java:293) [jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.java.invokers.InstanceMethodInvoker.call(InstanceMethodInvoker.java:24) [jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.java.invokers.InstanceMethodInvoker.call(InstanceMethodInvoker.java:86) [jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.targets.InvokeSite.invoke(InvokeSite.java:207) [jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at C_3a_.logstash.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.logstash_minus_output_minus_jdbc_minus_5_dot_4_dot_0.lib.logstash.outputs.jdbc.RUBY$method$setup_and_test_pool!$0(C:/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-jdbc-5.4.0/lib/logstash/outputs/jdbc.rb:169) [jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at C_3a_.logstash.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.logstash_minus_output_minus_jdbc_minus_5_dot_4_dot_0.lib.logstash.outputs.jdbc.RUBY$method$setup_and_test_pool!$0$__VARARGS__(C:/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-jdbc-5.4.0/lib/logstash/outputs/jdbc.rb) [jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.CompiledIRMethod.call(CompiledIRMethod.java:80) [jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:70) [jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.targets.InvokeSite.invoke(InvokeSite.java:207) [jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at C_3a_.logstash.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.logstash_minus_output_minus_jdbc_minus_5_dot_4_dot_0.lib.logstash.outputs.jdbc.RUBY$method$register$0(C:/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-jdbc-5.4.0/lib/logstash/outputs/jdbc.rb:127) [jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.CompiledIRMethod.call(CompiledIRMethod.java:93) [jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:105) [jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:192) [jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.RubyClass.finvoke(RubyClass.java:572) [jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.Helpers.invoke(Helpers.java:452) [jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.RubyBasicObject.callMethod(RubyBasicObject.java:354) [jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at org.logstash.config.ir.compiler.OutputStrategyExt$SimpleAbstractOutputStrategyExt.reg(OutputStrategyExt.java:275) [logstash-core.jar:?]
        at org.logstash.config.ir.compiler.OutputStrategyExt$AbstractOutputStrategyExt.register(OutputStrategyExt.java:131) [logstash-core.jar:?]
        at org.logstash.config.ir.compiler.OutputDelegatorExt.doRegister(OutputDelegatorExt.java:117) [logstash-core.jar:?]
        at org.logstash.config.ir.compiler.AbstractOutputDelegatorExt.register(AbstractOutputDelegatorExt.java:68) [logstash-core.jar:?]
        at org.logstash.config.ir.compiler.AbstractOutputDelegatorExt$INVOKER$i$0$0$register.call(AbstractOutputDelegatorExt$INVOKER$i$0$0$register.gen) [jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodN.call(JavaMethod.java:831) [jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.targets.InvokeSite.invoke(InvokeSite.java:207) [jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at C_3a_.logstash.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.java_pipeline.RUBY$block$register_plugins$1(C:/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:228) [jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.CompiledIRBlockBody.yieldDirect(CompiledIRBlockBody.java:148) [jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.BlockBody.yield(BlockBody.java:106) [jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.Block.yield(Block.java:184) [jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.RubyArray.each(RubyArray.java:1809) [jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.RubyArray$INVOKER$i$0$0$each.call(RubyArray$INVOKER$i$0$0$each.gen) [jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodZeroBlock.call(JavaMethod.java:555) [jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.targets.InvokeSite.invoke(InvokeSite.java:197) [jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at C_3a_.logstash.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.java_pipeline.RUBY$method$register_plugins$0(C:/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:227) [jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at C_3a_.logstash.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.java_pipeline.RUBY$method$register_plugins$0$__VARARGS__(C:/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb) [jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.CompiledIRMethod.call(CompiledIRMethod.java:80) [jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:70) [jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.targets.InvokeSite.invoke(InvokeSite.java:207) [jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at C_3a_.logstash.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.java_pipeline.RUBY$method$maybe_setup_out_plugins$0(C:/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:585) [jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at C_3a_.logstash.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.java_pipeline.RUBY$method$maybe_setup_out_plugins$0$__VARARGS__(C:/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb) [jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.CompiledIRMethod.call(CompiledIRMethod.java:80) [jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:70) [jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.targets.InvokeSite.invoke(InvokeSite.java:207) [jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at C_3a_.logstash.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.java_pipeline.RUBY$method$start_workers$0(C:/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:240) [jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at C_3a_.logstash.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.java_pipeline.RUBY$method$start_workers$0$__VARARGS__(C:/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb) [jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.CompiledIRMethod.call(CompiledIRMethod.java:80) [jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:70) [jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.targets.InvokeSite.invoke(InvokeSite.java:207) [jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at C_3a_.logstash.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.java_pipeline.RUBY$method$run$0(C:/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:185) [jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at C_3a_.logstash.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.java_pipeline.RUBY$method$run$0$__VARARGS__(C:/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb) [jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.CompiledIRMethod.call(CompiledIRMethod.java:80) [jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:70) [jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.targets.InvokeSite.invoke(InvokeSite.java:207) [jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at C_3a_.logstash.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.java_pipeline.RUBY$block$start$1(C:/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:137) [jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.CompiledIRBlockBody.callDirect(CompiledIRBlockBody.java:138) [jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.IRBlockBody.call(IRBlockBody.java:58) [jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.IRBlockBody.call(IRBlockBody.java:52) [jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.Block.call(Block.java:139) [jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:318) [jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.RubyRunnable.run(RubyRunnable.java:105) [jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) [?:?]
[2021-02-07T21:34:09,847][ERROR][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline error {:pipeline_id=>"main", :exception=>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection to the host DESKTOP-XXXX, named instance mssqlserver01 failed. Error: "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out". Verify the server and instance names and check that no firewall is blocking UDP traffic to port 1434.  For SQL Server 2005 or later, verify that the SQL Server Browser Service is running on the host., :backtrace=>["com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerException.java:191)", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.getInstancePort(com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerConnection.java:5247)", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.primaryPermissionCheck(com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerConnection.java:1871)", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerConnection.java:1608)", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerConnection.java:1459)", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerConnection.java:773)", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerDriver.java:1168)", "com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(com/zaxxer/hikari/util/DriverDataSource.java:117)", "com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(com/zaxxer/hikari/pool/PoolBase.java:375)", "com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(com/zaxxer/hikari/pool/PoolBase.java:204)", "com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(com/zaxxer/hikari/pool/HikariPool.java:445)", "com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(com/zaxxer/hikari/pool/HikariPool.java:516)", "com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(com/zaxxer/hikari/pool/HikariPool.java:116)", "com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(com/zaxxer/hikari/HikariDataSource.java:97)", "jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)", "jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(jdk/internal/reflect/NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)", "jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(jdk/internal/reflect/DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)", "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java/lang/reflect/Method.java:564)", "org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirectWithExceptionHandling(org/jruby/javasupport/JavaMethod.java:426)", "org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirect(org/jruby/javasupport/JavaMethod.java:293)", "C_3a_.logstash.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.logstash_minus_output_minus_jdbc_minus_5_dot_4_dot_0.lib.logstash.outputs.jdbc.setup_and_test_pool!(C:/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-jdbc-5.4.0/lib/logstash/outputs/jdbc.rb:169)", "C_3a_.logstash.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.logstash_minus_output_minus_jdbc_minus_5_dot_4_dot_0.lib.logstash.outputs.jdbc.RUBY$method$setup_and_test_pool!$0$__VARARGS__(C_3a_/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/$2_dot_5_dot_0/gems/logstash_minus_output_minus_jdbc_minus_5_dot_4_dot_0/lib/logstash/outputs/C:/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-jdbc-5.4.0/lib/logstash/outputs/jdbc.rb)", "C_3a_.logstash.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.logstash_minus_output_minus_jdbc_minus_5_dot_4_dot_0.lib.logstash.outputs.jdbc.register(C:/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-jdbc-5.4.0/lib/logstash/outputs/jdbc.rb:127)", "org.jruby.RubyClass.finvoke(org/jruby/RubyClass.java:572)", "org.jruby.RubyBasicObject.callMethod(org/jruby/RubyBasicObject.java:354)", "org.logstash.config.ir.compiler.OutputStrategyExt$SimpleAbstractOutputStrategyExt.reg(org/logstash/config/ir/compiler/OutputStrategyExt.java:275)", "org.logstash.config.ir.compiler.OutputStrategyExt$AbstractOutputStrategyExt.register(org/logstash/config/ir/compiler/OutputStrategyExt.java:131)", "org.logstash.config.ir.compiler.OutputDelegatorExt.doRegister(org/logstash/config/ir/compiler/OutputDelegatorExt.java:117)", "org.logstash.config.ir.compiler.AbstractOutputDelegatorExt.register(org/logstash/config/ir/compiler/AbstractOutputDelegatorExt.java:68)", "org.logstash.config.ir.compiler.AbstractOutputDelegatorExt$INVOKER$i$0$0$register.call(org/logstash/config/ir/compiler/AbstractOutputDelegatorExt$INVOKER$i$0$0$register.gen)", "C_3a_.logstash.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.java_pipeline.register_plugins(C:/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:228)", "org.jruby.RubyArray.each(org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1809)", "org.jruby.RubyArray$INVOKER$i$0$0$each.call(org/jruby/RubyArray$INVOKER$i$0$0$each.gen)", "C_3a_.logstash.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.java_pipeline.register_plugins(C:/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:227)", "C_3a_.logstash.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.java_pipeline.RUBY$method$register_plugins$0$__VARARGS__(C_3a_/logstash/logstash_minus_core/lib/logstash/C:/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb)", "C_3a_.logstash.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.java_pipeline.maybe_setup_out_plugins(C:/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:585)", "C_3a_.logstash.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.java_pipeline.RUBY$method$maybe_setup_out_plugins$0$__VARARGS__(C_3a_/logstash/logstash_minus_core/lib/logstash/C:/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb)", "C_3a_.logstash.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.java_pipeline.start_workers(C:/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:240)", "C_3a_.logstash.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.java_pipeline.RUBY$method$start_workers$0$__VARARGS__(C_3a_/logstash/logstash_minus_core/lib/logstash/C:/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb)", "C_3a_.logstash.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.java_pipeline.run(C:/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:185)", "C_3a_.logstash.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.java_pipeline.RUBY$method$run$0$__VARARGS__(C_3a_/logstash/logstash_minus_core/lib/logstash/C:/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb)", "C_3a_.logstash.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.java_pipeline.start(C:/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:137)", "org.jruby.RubyProc.call(org/jruby/RubyProc.java:318)", "java.lang.Thread.run(java/lang/Thread.java:832)"], "pipeline.sources"=>["c:/logstash/config/logs-pipeline.conf"], :thread=>"#<Thread:0x2cf682a3 run>"}
[2021-02-07T21:34:09,854][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline terminated {"pipeline.id"=>"main"}
[2021-02-07T21:34:09,874][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Failed to execute action {:id=>:main, :action_type=>LogStash::ConvergeResult::FailedAction, :message=>"Could not execute action: PipelineAction::Create<main>, action_result: false", :backtrace=>nil}
[2021-02-07T21:34:10,188][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
[2021-02-07T21:34:15,186][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Logstash shut down.
[2021-02-07T21:34:15,202][ERROR][org.logstash.Logstash    ] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logstash stopped processing because of an error: (SystemExit) exit
```

Comment: I think you need to enable TCP to use jdbc. SSMS uses named pipes for a local SQL Server instance

Comment: You're trying to connect using a Named Instance which requires that the SQL Browser Service is running and accessible via udp/1434. Have you followed the advice in the error message yet? _Error: "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out". Verify the server and instance names and check that no firewall is blocking UDP traffic to port 1434.  For SQL Server 2005 or later, verify that the SQL Server Browser Service is running on the host._